# it is possible to activate the tux text based logo in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: boot, kernel

the truth is that I get bored not having a logo during startup and yes, I don't mean Plymouth I mean the tux text based logo in addition to customizing the logo
I already tried to activate it from make menuconfig with an image made by me but I have not been able to activate it

[image]

Comment: This image is from your system? or a random example?

Comment: I took that image from google as an example